# Recreating a Photoshop Text Bevel In Illustrator

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator

I recently created a mock-up of a boat decal in Photoshop that looks like this.

**Photoshop Version**
[image]

However, for printing purposes, I need to vectorize it. I spent a little while in Illustrator (which I've never used before), and after some fiddling, was able to nearly recreate it.

**Vector Version without Bevel**
[image]

But you'll notice that the text bevel is missing. I've read through pages and pages of instructions about `Effect > 3d > Extrude & Bevel...`, I've sat there on that menu and tried 100 different things, but I can't get anything even *close* to the Photoshop version. It ends up looking like this:

**Attempt at Adding Bevel**
[image]

Is there a way to achieve this in Illustrator? Or, at this point, I'm even willing to ask the bigger question: What is the easiest way to vectorize  the Photoshop version, including the bevel?

Answer (score 3):

**This is Closest you can get to mimic the Bevel in Illustrator Using Just Blend Tool.**

---

### Process I followed to do that

1. Outline Your Text.
2. Make a 2 Copy of it.
3. Change Upper Copy's Color to #fffff/bright
4. Change Bottom Copy's Color To Gray/Dark & Slightly move Bottom Copy to down and right Using arrow key/mouse, Note that Only Move some PX to get smooth Bevel Like Effect.(Your Shade Matters on angle You Moved Bottom Copy)
5. Select Blend Tool & Click on Bottom copy and then Upper Copy. (Order is not mattered here!)
6. Align is Outlined Text and group it.

NOTE: Make Sure You Selected "Smooth Color" In Blend Option

[image: Note Picture]

---

#### Here is Presentation

[image: Bevel in Illustrator Using Blend Tool]